# \centering in minipage cannot be used

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm creating a notice environment,like [image: example],

the code is：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newenvironment{attention}
{\par\medskip\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep = 0pt] (box) \bgroup%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
%--------------------------------------------------------
    \raggedleft
%--------------------------------------------------------
    \tikz[scale = 1]\node[scale = 1, rotate = 0]{\bcattention};
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
    \begin{center}}% former part
{%
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \end{minipage}%
    \egroup;
    \draw[black,line width=1.5pt]
    ( $ (box.north east) + (-20pt,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.north east) + (-15pt,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.south east) + (-15pt,-3pt) $ ) -- + (-5pt,0);
    \draw[black,line width=1.5pt]
    ( $ (box.north west) + (20pt,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.north west) + (15pt,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.south west) + (15pt,-3pt) $ ) -- + (5pt,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{attention}
        Lorem...
    \end{attention}
\end{document}
```

and I'd like to let the exclamation mark icon be centered in the minipage, so I change the macro between `%------------------------` into `\centering`, but it's no use. Then I put the tikz macro into `{center}` environment, but it still no use. After that, I tried to use `\centerline` macro but nothing happened.

So how to do it?

Comment: Should the icon be centered between `[` and text or centered between `[` and `]`(centered in the whole mminipage)?

Comment: @Bobyandbob it should be centered between `[` and the text.

Comment: I’m not a Ti*k*Z expert, but if I recollect correctly a `node` has zero width and height.  Why are you using a `\tikz` command?  Why not simply `\bcattention`?

Comment: @GuM Yes, I  soon find this problem, So I wrote `\centering \bcattention`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a little different approach (without knowing, if the text in attention environment can be in more lines ... and consequently assuming that sign is the tallest element of "attention"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newsavebox{\att}
\newenvironment{attention}
    {\par\medskip\noindent
     \begin{lrbox}{\att}
    }% former part
    {\end{lrbox}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
\node (n1) [minimum width=0.17\textwidth]{\bcattention};
\node (n2) [text width=0.21\textwidth,
            right=of n1]{\usebox{\att}};
%
\draw[line width=1.5pt]
    ([xshift= 2mm] n1.north west) -| (n1.south west) -- + ( 2mm,0)
    ([xshift=-2mm] n1.north -| n2.east) -| (n2.east |- n1.south) -- + (-2mm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}

    \begin{attention}
        Lorem...
    \end{attention}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
in case, that a text in `attention` has more lines, than the above solution is necessary to adopt to this demand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newsavebox{\att}
\newenvironment{attention}
    {\par\medskip\noindent
     \begin{lrbox}{\att}
    \begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}% added
    }% former part
    {\end{minipage}% added
     \end{lrbox}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
every node/.style = {minimum width=0.17\textwidth, minimum height=11mm}% added
                        ]
\node (n1)                  {\bcattention};  % changed
\node (n2) [right=of n1]    {\usebox{\att}}; % changed
%
\draw[line width=1.5pt]
    ([xshift= 2mm] n1.west |- n2.north) -| (n1.west |- n2.south) -- + ( 2mm,0)
    ([xshift=-2mm] n2.north east) -| (n2.south east) -- + (-2mm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{attention}
        Lorem ipsum ...
    \end{attention}
    \begin{attention}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    \end{attention}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to break line in this environment, but the text went out the `]`, it maybe cannot auto break lines~~ @Zarko

Comment: @AllenWang, i must confess, that i was lost in your mwe, so i guess the width of nodes used in my mwe. if the text can be in more lines, than the coordinates for brackets had to be accordingly interchanged. I will add this situation to answer (asap)